# Pure and update Timer

Tags: android, timer

I try to update a timer previsously set in my Android app.

Timer code :

```
timer.purge();

Data.Log.i("Next update : "+time * 60 * 1000);

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wp.StartUpdate();
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, time * 60 * 1000);
```

So i cant update my timer. When i set it with "time = 2" every 2 minutes the timer execute even though I changed it to 60.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the timer is initialized, it stores the interval value of initialization time `time * 60 * 1000` which is equal to 2 minutes if `time = 2`. So this value is stored within timer object. Timer do not check this value at run-time, but uses its own locally stored value of interval which was supplied at initialization time.

If you change the value of `time = x` or any other, timer will not change its internal interval value. So if you want to change then interval value of timer later, You have to start another timer object with new interval value.

Comment: I added a function that delete the timer and re create it. I think i'ts ok.